# Accesing .space elements in MIPS (descending order)

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I want to get byte by byte from **.space** array, starting from the highest index.
I have two **.space** arrays, one for user to type in text, the second to store small letters from input string. 
There's a problem when I try to store byte in section change - **sb $t4,($t3)** doesn't seem to store right character or what's worse **$t4** doesn't seem to be pointing to last character of tmp anymore.
Is there some better way to acces chars in string from the end?

My code is meant to reverse order of small letters in inputted string,

here it is:

```
arr:    .space 100
tmp:    .space 100
che:    .asciiz "check\n"
text1:  .asciiz "input string: \n"
text2:  .asciiz "Output:\n"
    .text
    .globl main
main:
    li  $v0,4
    la  $a0, text1
    syscall

    la  $a0, arr
    li  $a1, 100
    li  $v0, 8
    syscall

    li  $t0, 'a'
    li  $t1, 'z'
    la  $t3,arr
    la  $t4,tmp
read_begin:
    lb  $t5,($t3)
    lb  $t6,($t4)
    beq     $t5,$zero,ch
    blt     $t5,$t0,increment
    bgt $t5,$t1,increment

    sb  $t5,($t4)
    addi    $t4,$t4,1
    b   increment

increment:
    addi    $t3,$t3,1
    b   read_begin
ch:
    la  $t3,arr
    b   change
change:

    lb  $t5,($t3)
    beq     $t5,$zero,end
    blt     $t5,$t0,increment2
    bgt $t5,$t1,increment2
    sb  $t4,($t3)
    addi    $t4,$t4,-1

increment2:
    addi    $t3,$t3,1
    b   change

end:

    li  $v0,4
    la  $a0, text2
    syscall
    la  $a0, arr                    
    li  $v0, 4                      
    syscall                         
    li  $v0, 10                     
    syscall
```

Comment: You should comment your code, especially if you want others to help. `sb  $t4,($t3)` doesn't make much sense since both `$t4` and `$t3` are pointers. You loaded the byte into `$t5` so I assume you really meant `sb $t5, ($t4)`.

Comment: @Jester **$t4** is meant to point to string consisting only small letters, I have to change characters in **arr**, which is pointed by **$t3**

Comment: Change them to what? In any case `$t4` is a pointer, you don't want to store it using `sb` anywhere so `sb  $t4,($t3)` still doesn't make any sense. Maybe you want to load from `($t4)` and store that? Then do something like `lb $t5, ($t4); sb $t5, ($t3)`.

Comment: @Jester This is exactly what I needed! Thank You! now I've fixed this